# How do I change background and font colors of the Items of a ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, listbox, gdi+

I created a formatting condition:

- If the text contains - **`Success`** then the background color is **`Green`**, ForeGround color is **`Black`**;
- If the text contains - **`Error`**" color background **`Red`**, foreground is **`Black`**;
- Other cases: background color is **`White`**, foreground color is **`Black`**;

**Question.**
How do I change background/foreground colors of the ListBox Item that I choose to fulfill *Condition 1*?

***Condition 1***. Condition for the selected Item:

- background `Color.Blue`;
- foreground `Color.White` (or `Color.Black`);

**Problem:**
My code does not paint the ListBox Item, which is `Color.White`.

```
private SolidBrush reportsForegroundBrushSelected = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
private SolidBrush reportsBackgroundBrushSelected = new SolidBrush(Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Highlight));

private SolidBrush reportsForegroundBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
private SolidBrush reportsBackgroundBrush1 = new SolidBrush(Color.LimeGreen);
private SolidBrush reportsBackgroundBrush2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Salmon);
private SolidBrush reportsBackgroundBrush3 = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    bool selected = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected);

    int index = e.Index;
    if (index >= 0 && index < listBox1.Items.Count)
    {
        string text = listBox1.Items[index].ToString();
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        //background:
        SolidBrush backgroundBrush;
        if (selected)
        {
            backgroundBrush = reportsBackgroundBrushSelected;
        }
        else
        {
            if (text.Contains("Success"))
            {
                backgroundBrush = reportsBackgroundBrush1;
            }
            else
            {
                backgroundBrush = reportsBackgroundBrush2;
            }
        }

        if (!text.Contains("Success") && !text.Contains("Error"))
        {
            backgroundBrush = reportsBackgroundBrush3;
        }

        g.FillRectangle(backgroundBrush, e.Bounds);

        //text:
        SolidBrush foregroundBrush = (selected) ? reportsForegroundBrushSelected : reportsForegroundBrush;
        g.DrawString(text, e.Font, foregroundBrush, listBox1.GetItemRectangle(index).Location);
    }
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wrong control, use ListView with View=List.

Answer (score 2):

Even though not explicitly requested, I suggest another way to manage the brushes that may, I think, simplify the ForeColor/BackColor switch and allows a better customization of the ListBox presentation.

Create a class object that contains all the brushes selection/pre-selections and exposes public properties to modify these values if/when needed.
Also, this class provides a method to return the correct combination of brushes, selecting the *right ones* based on a couple of conditions:

- The text content of the current Item
- Its selection Status (`Selected/Focused` or `NotAccelerator/NotFocusedRect`)

The class is quite simple.
It has an overloaded constructor that allows to specify default values or specific Color attributes to assign to the standard appearance of the ListBox control.

When using the default (empty) constructor, the default combination of ForeGround/BackGround Colors are set to `Color.Black` and `Color.White`:

```
public ReportsBrushes() : this(Color.White, Color.Black) { }
```

otherwise, it accepts 2 parameters, to set specific values:

```
public ReportsBrushes(Color ItemBackColor, Color ItemForeColor)
{
    this.StandardForeground = new SolidBrush(ItemForeColor);
    this.StandardBackground = new SolidBrush(ItemBackColor);
}
```

This simplifies the `ListBox.DrawItem` method:

```
private ReportsBrushes reportsBrushes = new ReportsBrushes();

private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var ctl = sender as ListBox;
    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();

    var itemColors = reportsBrushes.GetItemBrushes(ctl.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.Selected));

    using (StringFormat format = new StringFormat()) {
        format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(ctl.Items[e.Index].ToString(), ctl.Font, itemColors.ForeColor, e.Bounds, format);
    }
}

private void listBox1_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.ItemHeight = listBox1.Font.Height + 4;
}
```

The **`ReportsBrushes`** class:

```
internal class ReportsBrushes
{
    public ReportsBrushes() : this(Color.White, Color.Black) { }
    public ReportsBrushes(Color ItemBackColor, Color ItemForeColor)
    {
        this.StandardForeground = new SolidBrush(ItemForeColor);
        this.StandardBackground = new SolidBrush(ItemBackColor);
    }
    public SolidBrush StandardForeground { get; set; }
    public SolidBrush StandardBackground { get; set; }

    public SolidBrush SelectedForeground { get ; set ; } = 
        new SolidBrush(Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.HighlightText));
    public SolidBrush SelectedBackground { get; set; } = 
        new SolidBrush(Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Highlight));
    public SolidBrush SuccessBackground { get; set; } = 
        new SolidBrush(Color.LimeGreen);
    public SolidBrush ErrorBackground { get; set; } = 
        new SolidBrush(Color.OrangeRed);

    public (SolidBrush ForeColor, SolidBrush BackColor) GetItemBrushes(string ItemText, bool ItemSelected)
    {
        if (ItemSelected) {
            return (this.SelectedForeground, this.SelectedBackground);
        }
        else {
            if (ItemText.Contains("Success")) {
                return (this.StandardForeground, this.SuccessBackground);
            }
            if (ItemText.Contains("Error")) {
                return (this.StandardForeground, this.ErrorBackground);
            }
            return (this.StandardForeground, this.StandardBackground);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in your order of `if/else`.

Set it like this:

```
if (selected)
{
    backgroundBrush = reportsBackgroundBrushSelected;
}
else
{
    if (text.Contains("Success"))
    {
        backgroundBrush = reportsBackgroundBrush1;
    }
    else if(text.Contains("Error"))
    {
        backgroundBrush = reportsBackgroundBrush2;
    }
    else
    {
        backgroundBrush = reportsBackgroundBrush3;            
    }
}
```